# Flutter app slow

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying out Flutter and my app is responding very very slow on both the emulator and real device. I get warnings like this

> Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread.

I'm aware Dart is a single-threaded programming language and in Android I used to solve this with the good old `new Thread();` block for async. I am trying to apply the same in Flutter and I reading through `Future` `await` `async` and the sorts but the examples seem to be addressing when you reading data from the internet. My app doesn't read anything online at this stage, I'm getting Skipped x frames when my screen has progress dialog, when I am opening a new screen/page, and with every animation on the app. Here is an example of the class where I am getting the issue:

```
_buildContent(){
    return new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                (context) => new LoginScreen()));
          },
          child: new Container(
            height: 150.0,
            width: 150.0,
            child: new Image.asset("images/logo.png", fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          ),
        ),
        new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: null,
              strokeWidth: 1.0,
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                  Colors.white
              )
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

I'm assuming the skipped x frames warning is caused by the progress dialog? I have another screen (Login Screen) which animates widgets into place when opened, the animations move so slow, I can literally see each frame being rendered. Is there a tutorial online that can assist with addressing this or just understanding Dart's Asynchronous Programming?

Comment: Performance should be checked in release builds `flutter build apk --release`. Bigger images in animated widgets are known to cause performance issues.

Comment: `Future` isn't a different thread though

Comment: @spongyboxx this dialog shouldn't cause performance problem. You most likely have something that cost you a lot somewhere else. Try to use `Observatory` to trace what's costing that much.

Comment: And remember that futures aren't on a specific thread. They are just executed later on the main thread. So if you do expensive calculation inside a `Future`, it'll freeze your app

Comment: As both Gunter and Remi mentioned, [`Future` is not a thread](https://hackernoon.com/are-futures-in-dart-threads-2cdc5bd8063a).

Answer (score 49):

debug mode

- launch is slow
- blink when launch
- app size big.

because debug mode with Hot reloads.

when you create release apk   https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/android

you can find

- fast launch
- no blink during the launch
- app size small (but bigger than the normal android app)

**EDIT**

https://flutter.io/docs/testing/ui-performance#debug-flags

Debug mode enables additional checks (such as asserts) that don’t run in profile or release builds, and these checks can be expensive.
Debug mode also executes code in a different way than release mode. The debug build compiles the Dart code “just in time” (JIT) as the app runs, but profile and release builds are pre-compiled to native instructions (also called “ahead of time”, or AOT) before the app is loaded onto the device. JIT can cause the app to pause for JIT compilation, which itself can cause jank.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter%27s-modes

Debug mode on device (including simulators, emulators): Turns on all the assertions in the world, includes all debugging information, enables all the debugger aids (e.g. observatory) and service extensions. Optimizes for fast develop/run cycles. Does not optimize for execution speed, binary size, or deployment. Used by flutter run. Built with sky/tools/gn --android or sky/tools/gn --ios. Also sometimes called "checked mode" or "slow mode".

Answer (score 34):

Try running your app in release mode using `flutter run --release` in the terminal.

Answer (score 15):

Debug build has some performance issues, as many asserts and other validations happen in release build.
Release build is much more faster than debug build.

Running app in release build may help.
Try to run in release mode

```
flutter run --release
```

Answer (score 8):

You should take a look at the [Flutter performance Profiling](https://flutter.io/ui-performance/) guide. You can try different configurations to diagnose wether your problem is in the

- Platform thread
- UI thread
- GPU thread or
- I/O thread.

Even if your Dart code just runs in the Ui thread it can influence the other ones.

Answer (score 3):

There is a known issue in flutter where you have to "warm-up" the graphic api (SkSL) first. After a third run, usually the animation will become smooth.

The problem happens in both iOS an Android.

For iSO usually the lag occus in metal api as apple dropped support for OpenGL which is usally where skia graphic engine is implemented.

Work around and temporary solution are found on this page.

[Extreme jank on iOS/Android the first time any kind of animation or transition runs (release build) - skia shader compilation #61450](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61450)

Answer (score 1):

My app was running slow on some android devices, probably had some performance impact on other devices as well. The culprit was the image assets. After providing correct image sizes,

```
mdpi = 1x
hdpi = 1.5x
xhdpi = 2.0x
xxhdpi = 3.0x
xxxhdpi = 4.0x
```

to my assets folder and updating pubspec.yaml the performance got better,

```
assets:

- assets/images/
- assets/images/1.5x/
- assets/images/2.0x/
- assets/images/3.0x/
- assets/images/4.0x/
```

Answer (score 1):

**iOS simulators**

If you are experiencing slowness, low FPS, laggy scrolling on specific (newer) devices **in Xcode simulator** that's because Apple dropped support for OpenGL and Flutter SDK does not support the new Metal API **in simulators**.

But the official stable support will be available soon, until that if you need 60 FPS, switch to the master channel of Flutter SDK by running this in terminal and rebuild your app:

```
flutter channel master
```

sources:

[iOS Simulator gradually becomes very slow & unusable](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36839)

[Investigate enabling Metal on iOS simulators above version 13.0.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52358)

[Will Flutter use Metal on iOS Simulators?](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Metal-on-iOS-FAQ#will-flutter-use-metal-on-ios-simulators)

Answer (score 0):

If you still find slowness after checking in profile mode, here is a new solution: https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_smooth.

Shortly speaking, your app will be ~60FPS smooth, even though its build/layout can be arbitrarily slow. How to use it and how it is implemented can be found in the doc.

Disclaimer: I made that library.

Answer (score 0):

if you are experiencing laggy ios simulator the only solution for me was creating iPhone SE. then it started working as smooth as it was before.