# Data from API takes a lot of time to load in webview

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, webview

When I want to display API data on the iOS Flutter webview, the page takes about 10 seconds to load. Are there any specific settings for that?

the following code that I use

```
             child: WebView(
                //  controller: _webViewController,
                initialUrl: new Uri
                    .dataFromString(
                    "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1'/>" //IOS KONFIGURASI TEXT NORMAL DI EBVIEW
                        "${widget.s_content}",
                    mimeType: 'text/html')
                    .toString(),

                //initialUrl: '${dataQuestions["list_question"][_counter]["data_option"][loop]["option_text"]}',

                javascriptMode:
                JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onPageFinished: (finish) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
              )
```

**EDIT:**
On real device the data loads fast but only in the emulator takes time to load.

Comment: So it takes 10 seconds to load your data in the web view?

Comment: yes, I tried it on the emulator it took a long time but I tried it on the original device loading the data quite fast, it seems like the problem is on my device

Comment: There is a github discussion on same. Can you check this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36839

Comment: Also check if this is similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255091/flutter-app-slow